# Optimizing condition clause in CASE statement when querying external table

Tags: sql, case

I have 02 tables as following:

TableA:

| Id | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 3 | C | 2 |

TableB:

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

What I want to do is performing a SELECT query, if the Id in table A is also in Table B, then set state = 0, otherwise 1

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    CASE WHEN a.Id IN (SELECT * FROM TableB) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS State,
FROM TableA as a
```

Expected output as:

| Id | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 0 |

My given query works as expectation, but I wonder if my way is the optimal way or not. Especailly in this part:

```
a.Id IN (SELECT * FROM TableB)
```

Since as I understand, every single Id in tableA will need to be checked , and when that happens, all the Id in Table B will be queried over and over again. This doesn't sounds like performance friendly to me.

What would you suggest in this case to increase the query performance ? I tried with JOIN, but i can't mimic the behavior of CASE statement (that allows me to perform check then assigning new value )

Thank you.

Comment: Look at a JOIN instead of sub select in you IN statement.  You can use LEFT join then on your column value use your case still but pointing to the column value instead of the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids are unique in `B`, then you can use:

```
select a.*,
       (case when b.id is not null then 0 else 1 end) as state
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

For performance for this or your version of the query, you want an index on `b(id)` -- even better if it is the primary key.

Comment: This indeed helps. I tested both queries on a sample dataset. The join style gave  around 15% improvement in the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Move your select from tableB to a join, to get better performance. They way you have written your query, it will execute the the select statement in your select for every row returned by the outer select query.

Using a join will only execute it once and get the results much more efficiently. something like this....

```
SELECT 
      a.ID
    , a.Name
    , CASE WHEN b.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [State]
FROM TableA a 
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you. I marked Gordon’answer as accepted since he was a bit faster.